# When I pressed enter as an input, my program does not print anything

Tags: java, input, enter

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = "name";
      int low = 0;
      int high = 0;
      int count = 0;
      double dnum = 0.0; 
      while(name!=null) {
         try {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                  low = scanner.nextInt();
                  high = scanner.nextInt();
                  count = scanner.nextInt();
                  name = null;
               } else if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                  dnum = scanner.nextDouble();
                  System.out.print(dnum + " is not integer");
                  name = null;
               } else {
                  System.out.print("User enter only enter");
                  name = null;
               }
            }
         } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.print(dnum + "is not integer");
            name=null;
            System.out.print(low);
            System.out.print(high);
         }
      }
   scanner.close(); 
   }
}
```

When I pressed enter as an input, my program does not print anything. But If I replace `new Scanner(System.in)` with `new Scanner("\n")`, the program work as I expected. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: When you press `Enter` does the program finish?

Comment: The difference between the two is that when you press enter in your input, the program may expect more (through the `hasNextInt()` method). However, the `Scanner` constructed using just the String `"\n"` knows that there is no more input after just that character. It will return `false` straight away to the `hasNextInt` call.

Comment: If you want to input from the console, and you want blank input lines to be meaningful, don't use `[has]nextInt()`.  Instead, just input entire lines with `nextLine()`, and break up the lines yourself.  `nextInt()` will keep looking through input until it finds something, and if you give it a blank line, it will just wait for the next line.